# etcd: change resilient recursive wait

Tags: etcd

etcd allows clients to safely wait for changes of individual k/v nodes, by supplying a last known index of a node to the wait command. etcd also allows to wait ("recursively") for any changes to child nodes under a certain parent node.

Now, the problem is: is it possible to recursively wait on a parent node in such a way, as to guarantee that no child node changes are ever missed by the client? Parent node index is of no use in this case, as it would not change on child node modification.

Comment: I thought the the index of the parent changed if any of its children changed. Been a while since I messed with it but I think that's the case. It should be easy enough to test by creating a dir, some child nodes, and see if the index of the parent is always >= the index of its children.

Comment: @Oliver No, directory change index does not reflect changes to its children. In fact, it appears that etcd has no mechanism to propagate change events across the directory hierarchy at all - it's each key to itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting up, presumably you have just retrieved the subtree you're watching. The reply has an etcd_index field. Use that as the starting point.

Otherwise, your wait contains the modification index of the change. Use that as a starting point for the next call.

You may have to increase one or two of these values to ensure that you don't get duplicate replies. I don't remember which of these I need to increment on purpose; the code needs tests which ensure that I get every change exactly once, so I adjust the values based on that.

Comment: This is not what the question is about. Kindly read it again.

Comment: So what problem *are* you trying to solve, if this answer doesn't help?

You get the initial index you need to start watching at by reading the tree, which presumably you do anyway if you then watch for changes on it. If not, store the index you've read up to someplace (like in an "_upto_here" node on the tree in question).

In any case, there can't be an absolute guarantee since etcd only stores the last 1000 changes.